# How to update a row with the first value of that group if another column matches?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

My issue is pretty straight forward, all of the queries we have tried error out. I am a novice user and am still learning the SQL language, any help would be very appreciated.

I'm attempting to update a table to where if the rate column matches `Mat ID` will update with the first value from that grouping.

```
+------+--------+
| Rate | Mat ID |
+------+--------+
| 1    | 81     |
| 2    | 82     |
| 2    | 83     |
| 3    | 85     |
| 2    | 86     |
| 2    | 87     |
| 3    | 88     |
+------+--------+
```

Expected result:

```
+------+--------+
| Rate | Mat ID | 
+------+--------+
| 1    | 81     |
| 2    | 82     |
| 2    | 82     |
| 3    | 85     |
| 2    | 82     |
| 2    | 82     |
| 3    | 85     |
+------+--------+
```

Comment: Please provide examples of the SQL you have already tried and the error messages you have mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the following:

- Your definition of 'first' means the minimum value per grouping.
- Typo on the last row in your expected results should be `85` and not `88`.

The following `UPDATE` statement meets your requirements:

```
;
WITH    CTE_MinMatID
          AS (
              SELECT    Rate,
                        MIN(MatID) MinMatID
              FROM      @table
              GROUP BY  Rate
             )
    UPDATE  t
    SET     t.MatID = cte.MinMatID
    FROM    @table AS t
    INNER JOIN CTE_MinMatID cte ON cte.Rate = t.Rate;
```

[Working example here](https://gist.github.com/chrispickford/6a5b2369b91a57a13c628dc52b1e854f).

Comment: You are good my friend, thanks for helping out a novice. It did exactly what I was needing it to do. I still have A LOT to learn.